# get an hour wrong when using UNIX_TIMESTAMP and time()

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have set my mysql db: `SET time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';`
and in php

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

but when I add

```
$time = strtotime ("+2 minutes");
```

and

```
$time2 = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

to the db i get wrong an hour wrong when I get it from mysql like this:

```
        $query ="select UNIX_TIMESTAMP("time"), time2 from tbl; 
        if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $unix_time = $row["UNIX_TIMESTAMP("time")"];
                $unix_time2 = $row["time2"];
            }
            $result->close();
        }       ,

echo gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unix_time)." | ".gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unix_time2)." ";
```

displays:

`2010-12-26 01:06:48` | `2010-12-26 02:06:24`

Comment: If you are running your own server, I suggest you adjust your os's timezone. Then you simply restart mysql daemon and it will read that timezone.

What OS are you using? 
Are you on a shared hosting account?
do you have shell access?

Comment: `select UNIX_TIMESTAMP("time")` = 0, 1 warnings `Incorrect datetime value: 'time'`, something missing in your code?

Comment: your code has syntax errors, can you post the code using pastebin.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unix_timestamp()` will retrieve your local timestamp, which is currently in daylight savings mode. `gmdate()` works off Greenwhich Mean Time, aka UTC, which has no DST, so you'll get the 1 hour difference. Use `date()` instead of `gmdate()` to work with DST-awareness.

Comment: how to explain the 24 seconds differences?

Comment: Given your code snippet above has syntax errors (double-quotes embedded in double-quote strings?), no way to tell how the code works. But if your mysql server is on a different machine/vm, then a time difference is entirely possible. PHP would be going off the local system clock, and mysql would be going off the other machine's clock.